# How can i restrict Cross-site Attacks? Even All Patches are Installed

Tags: magento-1.9

I am Using magento 1.9.1.0. Now I was Scanned My website by third party scanning . Now i seen the Cross Site Script on my website, How can i restrict the Cross site Scripting in my site. Please Help me.